# Chinese characters on PDF (laravel-dompdf)

Tags: css, laravel, internationalization, dompdf

I'm trying to show some Chinese characteres in my PDF; but it is proving much more complicated than I had imagined.

I'm using the vendor [laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) and  I tried with a lot of fonts like: `Fyrefly Sung`, `SimHei`, `SimSun`, `Unifont` as follow:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: SimHei;
    src: url('{{base_path()."/public/assets/fonts/fireflysung.ttf"}}') format('truetype');
}
.chinese{
    font: Arial 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-family:  Firefly Sung;
}
```

As well with a CDN:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Firefly Sung';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(http://foo.bar/fireflysung.ttf) format('truetype');
}
.chinese{
    font: Arial 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-family:  Firefly Sung;
}
```

Example:

```
<span class="chinese">不含弹性织物</span>
```

But I can't get it work, since my PDF shows other chinese characters:

```
ゴム部を除く
```

Comment: I solved a similar problem with this comment https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/79#issuecomment-257003345

Comment: @istaro I will take a look, thank you!

Comment: @istaro Still the same problem; but thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem:

I remove the call of the `output()` method before call `stream()`:

```
// $pdf->output();
return $pdf->stream($myPDFName);
```

And now works as expected.